# Quale sarebbe l'avverbio di "Nemmeno il tuo cane ha abbaiato"?

Tags: adverbs

C'è un esercizio del libro "Italiano Facile - Percorso Semplificato di grammatica" che chiede: "Nelle frasi che seguono, sottolinea gli avverbi e scrivi in fianco qual è il loro significato":

> Nemmeno il tuo cane ha abbaiato

---

L'avverbio sarebbe "nemmeno" però non so di che tipo. Ho il dubbio tra avverbi di tempo e avverbi di valutazione.
Cosa pensate?

Comment: Mi sono permesso qualche piccola correzione alla tua domanda. In particolare, nota che non si dice *“il avverbio”, ma “l'avverbio”; e non si scrive *“sò” ma “so”. Inoltre “scrivi in fianco” suona molto strano; in genere si dice “scrivi a fianco”. Sei sicuro che il tuo libro dica così?

Comment: Non mi sembra che ti stiano chiedendo il “tipo” dell'avverbio, ma solo il significato. Quello lo sai?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non sono completamente sicura che questa sia una risposta alla domanda perché, come ho detto in un commento, non mi è del tutto chiara.

Non credo esista un unico modo di classificare gli avverbi. Sul [sito sito Vivit dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.viv-it.org/schede/l-avverbio) puoi vedere che si raggruppano in queste categorie:

> - Avverbi qualificativi
> - Avverbi determinativi
> - Avverbi valutativi: affermativi, negativi, di dubbio
> - Avverbi interrogativi ed esclamativi

Nel glossario che appare alla fine dell'*Italiano* di Serianni si può leggere:

> Dal punto di vista del significato, gli avverbi possono essere suddivisi in:
>   *qualificativi o di modo*; *di tempo*; *di luogo*; *di quantità*; *di giudizio* (di affermazione e di negazione, di dubbio); *interrogativi* ed *esclamativi*; *presentativi*.

Come puoi vedere nella [pagina dedicata agli avverbi valutativi del sito Vivit](http://www.viv-it.org/schede/avverbi-valutativi-affermativi-negativi-di-dubbio), "nemmeno" è considerato un "avverbio negativo" (o "di negazione") che rientra nei cosiddetti "avverbi valutativi", chiamati "avverbi di giudizio" nel libro di Serianni.

Per saperne il significato bisognerebbe avere la frase in contesto, ma sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nemmeno_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) puoi vedere che vuol dire lo stesso di "neanche" o "neppure". Alla [voce "neanche" del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/neanche) si trova una delle accezioni possibili:

> serve a escludere proprio quello che sarebbe più facile credere o ammettere: *neanche un bambino si lascerebbe ingannare in quel modo* (= persino un bambino non ...)

Cioè, la frase della domanda significherebbe "persino il tuo cane non ha abbaiato" in una situazione in cui ci si sarebbe aspettato il contrario.

Potrebbe essere che ci fosse un'altra frase negativa prima di quella della domanda, che raccontasse di altri cani che non hanno abbaiato. Allora, il significato sarebbe questo:

> Può aggiungere una negazione ad altra precedente, espressa o sottintesa: «*Non mi sono mosso di casa; e tu*?» «*Neanch’io*» (= anch’io non)

Cioè, il senso della frase sarebbe "anche il tuo cane non ha abbaiato".

Comment: Grazie per la tua risposta Charo, l'italiano non è la mia madrelingua allora cerco di essere il più chiaro possibile ed a volte non riesco a farlo